# Changing button height in xcode 8 not applying changes in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I'm using Xcode 8 to maintain an iOS app written in objective C.

When adjusting the size of a button (either via the interface builder or through the source code) the change is not applied in the Simulator.

Comment: upload button screen with changes that you applied and not affected in simulator.

Comment: did you apply constraints ?

Comment: yes constraints applied